# Syntax Error unexpected token u in json at position 0 in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting Syntax Error unexpected token u in json at position 0 in node js while posting any data. In postman, first i sign in and get the token from that. And set header token Authorization before posting any blog. But i am always getting Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0

This is code related to posting blog

```
const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const Category = require("../models/category");
const Tag = require("../models/tags");
const formidable = require("formidable");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const stripHtml = require("string-strip-html");
const _ = require("lodash");
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");
const fs = require("fs");

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Image could not upload",
      });
    }

    const { title, body, categories, tags } = fields;

    let blog = new Blog();
    blog.title = title;
    blog.body = body;
    blog.slug = slugify(title).toLowerCase();
    blog.mtitle = `${title} | ${process.env.APP_NAME}`;
    blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));
    blog.postedBy = req.user._id;

    if (files.photo) {
      if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Image should be less then 1mb in size",
        });
      }
      blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
      blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
    }

    blog.save((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler(err),
        });
      }
      res.json(result);
    });
  });
};
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();
// bring routes
const blogRoutes = require("./routes/blog");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const categoryRoutes = require("./routes/category");
const tagRoutes = require("./routes/tags");

// app
const app = express();

// db
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE_CLOUD, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB connected"))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// middlewares
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
// cors
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(cors({ origin: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}` }));
}
// routes middleware
app.use("/api", blogRoutes);
app.use("/api", authRoutes);
app.use("/api", userRoutes);
app.use("/api", categoryRoutes);
app.use("/api", tagRoutes);

// port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is error i am getting and it's hard to determine from which i am getting the
error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\763850\Downloads\blog\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\763850\Downloads\blog\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\763850\Downloads\blog\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\763850\Downloads\blog\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\763850\Downloads\blog\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\763850\Downloads\blog\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that usually means you're trying to parse `undefined` - which line of your code throws the error though, that could be important

Comment: I know that one. But could you help me with that issue, that's why i posted the code here

Comment: yes ... you did post the code ... but please inform us of which line of that code throws the error

Comment: All the error show from node_module. It doesn't throw the error from specific file. That's reason for me also hard to debugg

Comment: so, all you get on the server is `Syntax Error unexpected token u in json at position 0` with absolutely no indication of which line of code is throwing that error? That's pretty unusual ... usually a thrown error outputs a stack trace

Comment: in `blog.save((err, result)` - can you `console.log(result)` that seems the most likely place that something is trying to parse `undefined`

Comment: after your edit ... it looks like the client is sending `undefined` - since body-parser seems to be the source of the error - so the real source of the error seems to be that somewhere the client code is sending `undefined` instead of valid JSON

Comment: As of now i am not using any client. it's just the api i am building. I put the console where you told but i am not getting anything there

Comment: `As of now i am not using any client` ... huh? so, what is accessing your routes on your server? ... oh, wait "In postman" ... so **postman** is your client

Comment: Yeah using postman i am doing that stuff. I have mentioned in description already

Comment: well, it seems you *may* be using it wrong when you are "posting any blog"

Comment: @Vickram I have the same error...did you find any solutions yet?? If so please help as I am unable to find any solutions.